# TestNG with Eclipse: How to add main class?

Tags: automated-testing, testng

How can I add main class in eclipse cucumber project. I am running cucumber feature file and using TestNG but getting error: "cannot find class in classpath" and as a resolution of this I am geeting solution as add main class. Can anyone have another solution related to it.

```
error: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: crossfit.test.CroddfitRunner
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your testng.xml file. 
See this example:

```
<test name="Smoke Test"> 
<classes>
 <class name="packagename.classname"> </class>
 </classes>
 </test>
```

In , you must enter your tests package name before name of class that you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link and you can ask query here.

```
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495
```

The above link didn't work it means you need a higher version of TestNG for the eclipse. Before that check TestNG is installed or not in order to know that press CTRL+N in the wizard you can see TestNG class file name.

If it is not displaying then try installing TestNG In Eclipse IDE Via Offline Jar Files:

1)Download the latest TestNG Jar files from the link TestNg Jars ("https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse") 
2)Download TestNG 6.11, Clicking on the link will download the “site_assembly.zip” file for the TestNG version 6.11. This file contains two folders named as “features” and “plugins“.Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “dropins” folder there. 
3)Create a folder inside the dropins folder and name it as “testng-eclipse-6.11“ 
4)Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its contents to the newly created “testng-eclipse-6.11” directory. 
5)Restart Eclipse

OR

Go click on Help> Install new Software> Under Available software> Work with textbox paste this "2019-06 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-06" and then click on ADD. You will now see the files like TestNG and a lot of many others. Select TestNG click on Next> Next> Accept the condtions> Finish. It will restart the eclipse. Inorder to know the installation is successful Press CTRL+N.